# «Mогла быть использована» или «могла использоваться»?

Tags: морфология

1. Мачта могла быть использована повторно.
2. Мачта могла использоваться повторно.

Есть ли разница? Может ли (2) употребляться как (1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте сначала поймем, что означает слово *повторно*.

[Грамота пишет](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_156): Повторно – это только во второй раз, а не в третий, четвертый и т. д. (в таком случае следовало бы употреблять наречие *неоднократно* или конкретно указывать, в который раз)

Значит речь идет об однократно совершенном действии (повторном использовании мачты).

Если вы хотите подчеркнуть сам факт использования (мачтой воспользовались), то требуется глагол или причастие **совершенного** вида. Подходит причастие *использована*:

**Мачта могла быть использована повторно.**

Если вы хотите подчеркнуть процесс использования (мачтой пользовались), то требуется глагол **несовершенного** вида. Подходит глагол *использоваться*:

**Мачта могла использоваться повторно.**

Comment: спасибо, особенно за «повторно». Хоть этого не быть в вопросе, но нужно именно «неоднократно». Интересно, совершенность/несовершенность действия  влияет на значение наречия «повторно», которое описывает действие? Ведь если действие не совершено, процесс, то и наречие «лонгируется», и после первого повторного использования могло быть и второе, и третье, действие ведь не совершённое, не законченное.

Comment: (1) Я как-то не могу "прочувствовать" ситуацию. Мачта — не одноразовая посуда, ее используют многократно. К чему это "могла быть"? (2) Отвечая на Ваш вопрос: чтобы было повторное второе, должно быть повторное первое. Заразился гриппом — заразился повторно -— выздоровел — заразился гриппом — заразился повторно — выздоровел....

Comment: Similar to the clamps that held the Saturn V down while the engines spooled up. The clamp had a special hood it retracted into. It protect the clamps from rocket exhaust so they could be reused for multiple launches.                                   _Похожая пусковая мачта держала Сатурн-5 пока двигатели разогревались. Специальный карман, в который складывалось крепление, защищал его от ракетного выхлопа, т.о. мачта могла быть использована неоднократно._   (2) Я не понял ваш ответ.

Comment: т.е. если бы у мачты не было бы этого кармана и крепление разрушалось бы после каждого взлёта, то мачта уже не смогла бы использоваться неоднократно.

Comment: (1) It protect**s** or It protect**ed** (*it protect* is not correct) (2) Теперь понятно (я-то думал о корабельной мачте). Оба варинта корректны: "Мачта могла быть использована неоднократно." , "Мачта могла использоваться неоднократно". (3) Чтобы говорить о втором повторном использовании, нужно иметь второе первичное использование, некие циклы.